# Nested queries with NodeJs, Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

This is a bit of a beginner question and excuse my lack of knowledge.

I am trying to return a sub-query based off a query in my Node.js and Google Firebase server App.

In my "Get Authenticated User" request, I use the following code to call "User" collection and find the "UserRoles" as here:

```js
let propertyData = {};
  db.doc(`/users/${req.user.uid}`)
    .get()
    .then(async (doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        propertyData.credentials = doc.data();
        return db
          .collection("userRoles")
          .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid)
          .get();
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data 1  ", data);
      propertyData.roles = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        propertyData.roles.push(doc.data());

        for (const property of propertyData.roles) {
          let propsToQuery = [];
          data.forEach((doc) => {
            propsToQuery.push({
              propertyId: doc.data().propertyId,
            });
          });
          return db
            .collection("properties")
            .where("propertyId", "array-contains", propsToQuery)
            .get();
        }
      });
```

hope this makes sense....

Comment: Could you please share your Firestore structure? And explain more briefly what you are trying to achieve. Are you getting any errors with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was achieve what I was looking for with the following ...

```
db.doc(`/users/${req.user.uid}`)
.get()
.then((doc) => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    userData.credentials = doc.data();
    return db
      .collection("userRoles")
      .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid)
      .get();
  }
})
.then((data) => {
  userData.roles = [];
  data.forEach((doc) => {
    userData.roles.push(doc.data());
    propertyIds.push(doc.data().propertyId);
  });
  console.log("Prop ids list:  ", propertyIds);

  return db
    .collection("properties")
    .where("propertyId", "in", propertyIds)
    .orderBy("propertyName", "asc")
    .get();
})
.then((data ........ )
```

Please note- where I was going wrong- and again basic answer for a basic question, but I needed to the parameter of "in" for when I was executing the query (vs. array-contains). Still new so understanding the differences better, but posting this in-case it helps anyone else

Answer (score 0):

Please add async await to wait for the inner promise to finish, use the following code:

```
Please use async await in the first then as following: *** db.doc(`/users/${req.user.uid}`)
.get()
.then(async (doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        userData.credentials = doc.data();
        return await db
            .collection("userRoles")
            .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid)
            .get();
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks- I have done that, but still not getting the return- just updating my code above